# Why is reactive dataset, in RShiny, with NA value considered as "empty" dataset in validation?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

Can somebody help me please? In my application, the user can upload a file from the device. The application has a number of features that do not matter now. The point is that when performing validation **is reactive dataset, in RShiny,  with NA value considered as "empty" dataset** and "warning message" does not disappear despite the uploaded dataset. Is there some way how to resolve it ? (In my example: After upload dataset with NA value there is still message **Please, upload dataset at first!** )

**SERVER:**

```
##########################################
#dataset upload

df1 <- reactiveVal()
  observeEvent(input$file1,{
    df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                   header = input$header,
                   sep = input$sep,
                   quote = input$quote)
    df1(df)
  })
##########################################


##########################################
#example of function where I use validation  


#Delete column
  output$to_delete<- renderUI({
     validate(
       need(df1() != "", "Please, upload dataset at first!")
     )
    
    choice <- names(df1())
    selectInput('to_delete', label = 'Choose column to delete: ', choices = choice)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$del_col, {
    df1(df1()[ , !names(df1()) %in% c(input$to_delete)])
  })
  ##########################################
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want `need(df1() != "", ...)` to *not* display "upload dataset" when `df1()` yields `NA`?

Comment: That's not *"`NA` in `df1()`"*, that is *"`df1()` is exactly just `NA`"*. The two are different. `shiny::isTruthy(data.frame(a=NA))` is true, so it will not print "upload dataset"; `shiny::isTruthy(NA)` is false, so it will print it. Have you used `browser()` to ensure that `df1()` is actually holding valid data?

Comment: In that example I want to see opinions when I upload dataset with NA. It works when I upload dataset without NA (message disappears), but whne I upload dataset with NA message is still here

Comment: I just want to create a condition: if the dataset is not uploaded show the message >"Please, upload dataset at first!".

Comment: But why when I upload dataset without NA it works ? Beafore upload there is message: "Please, upload dataset at first!" and after upload dataset without NA message disappears.

Comment: ***Any*** `data.frame()`, with or without `NA`, with or without rows in general, will be marked as "truthy", see `shiny::isTruthy(data.frame())`. There is a clear difference between "my object is exactly and only one `NA`", and "my object is a frame that contains at least one `NA`". It's a little interesting to me that you care to add `validate(need(..))` there, but choose to not use `req(input$file1)` in your other observe blocks (where you should also be doing validation/requirements checks).